# Posts Per Page with a button to add more Posts

Tags: php, recent-posts

I have `$recent_posts` array with a `'posts_per_page'` that look like thah:

```
<?php
  $num_per_page = 3;
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => $num_per_page,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
  ));
  foreach($recent_posts as $post) : ?>
```

I would like to add a button that can expand the posts amount in a 3 at a time in every click on it..

Comment: Please check this post this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress

Comment: @Bhupen Thanks :)